# Не работает стиль css (Bootstrap + Spring)

Tags: java, html, css, веб-программирование, spring

Я хочу через css сделать ограничения чтобы моя таблица не во всю длины была на JSP странице, так вот я написал код но он не работает может не правильно расположил его
Вот мой проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот мои коды

AllStudent JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>All Users</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <div class="it">
    <h3>List of all Students</h3>
    ${message}
    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Surname</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>${student.name}</td>
                    <td>${student.surname}</td>
                     <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>


    </table>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить студента</button></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Я хочу кнопку показать всех студентов ровно по центру сделать и фон чтобы задний был вроде бы все написал почему не работает можете посмотреть

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%></style>


        <title>Home Page</title>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class ="pokaz">





            <form action="allStudents" method="post">


                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">

            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#bg{

 background-image: url("img/start.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.it{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}


.pokaz{

   margin: auto auto; 

}
```

Comment: такое чувство, что ты любой вопрос пишешь сюда :-(

Comment: Вы используете класс `class="btn btn-primary"` , он из bootStrap?

Comment: да он от туда...

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-center), возможно вам поможет данная информация. К сожалению, я почти не разбираюсь в WEB. Вы можете попробовать с помощью браузера (Средства разработчика) отцентровать ваш элемент средствами CSS, а потом полученный код перенести в ваш CSS файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя не импортирован внутри тега  твой файл со стилями.
 Добавь его, например так

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Также, глянь вот на [сайт](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/) этого парня. У него много интересного по Java

**P.S**

Также, можете попробовать переместить ваш css и img внутрь WEB-INF, как положено и в вашем jsp использовать

```
<style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%></style>
```

Comment: Я правил код посмотрите правильно ли написал, просто не работает

Comment: попробуйте удалить первый `stylesheet` который указан в самом начале

Comment: это бутстраповски стайлшит его удалил и таблица сломалась

Comment: @СтивГейтс обновил ответ, проверьте

Comment: Спасибо сработала)

Comment: @СтивГейтс, пожалуйста)

Comment: Вы тут на сайте??

Comment: @СтивГейтс, ДА )

Comment: Можете посмотреть я правил код